# How to change X-Frame-Option in dhis-live

Tags: dhis2

Where is the config for `X-Frame-Option` in dhis-live? 
I know it has security reason to put `X-Frame-Option` equal to sameorigin but I am going to change it.

Answer (score 1):

DHIS 2 Live is based on an embedded Jetty web server. That setting is currently not exposed or possible to change unfortunately.